# Pandas How to resample column with strings

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with: date;name
The point is if I do a resample using something like:

```
df.set_index('date').resample('D')["name"].sum()
```

The result concatenates all names from the resampling in one cell without separator. I want to be able to count name occurrences and plot it.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Rolling.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.count.html):

```
s =  df.set_index('date').resample('D')["name"].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks actually count and groupby is perfect:

```
df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])['name'].count()
```